# Java's .sort() method breaks the while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

Recently started learning Java and during implementing the "binary search" found out that if I call the Arrays.sort() on the array I am about to search in, it makes the loop to be infinite. Removing/commenting out the line solves the problem, but I cannot get why. My intension is to pass the sorted array to the .binarySearch() method. Tried to figure out with debugger but could not. Don't want to leave this question without the answer, can anyone, please, help?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    static class BinarySearch {
        int binarySearch(int[] array, int value) {
            int low = 0;
            int high = array.length - 1;

            while (low <= high) {
                int mid = low + high / 2;
                int guess = array[mid];

                if (guess == value) {
                    return mid;
                } else if (guess > value) {
                    high = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    low = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearch bs = new BinarySearch();
        int[] a = {1, 3, 4, 45, 54, 666, 2, 4};
        Arrays.sort(a);

        int result = bs.binarySearch(a, 45);

        if (result == -1) {
            System.out.println("value not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("value found at position: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrays.sort doesn't really have anything to do with you ending up with an infinite loop. It's the way you calculate mid.

Should've been `(low + high) / 2`. You seem to have forgot to add parentheses.

Comment: Indeed! Looks like it is enough of Java for me for today :) Thank you very much!!